Number of successes for correlated Bernoulli variables
The number of successes for a given set of independent Bernoulli random variables is described by the binomial distribution. However, I was wondering what could be said if the Bernoulli variables were correlated. For example, in the case of sampling without reinsertion then the number of successes is described by a hypergeometric distribution, but it is a special case (equivalent to extracting balls from an urn without then reinserting them). Could you suggest me some texts where the problem of the total number of successes for correlated Bernoulli variables is addressed in a slightly more generic way?

You'd need to address what the form of dependence is. Are you envisioning knowing a large set of pairwise correlations between each pair of Bernoulli variates? Some special structure that induces some constant correlation between all of them? Something else? There's some  simplification in the case of the Bernoulli that you don't get more generally, but you'd still need some sense of what you're doing.

I wrote the long answer first, then realized you are after a book. Will keep the answer just in case. Books. I liked this one:
Christian H. Weiss An Introduction to Discrete-Valued Time Series

You can try to put some structure around this as follows. You have an ordered sequence of binary variables: $\,X_0,\,X_1,\,X_2,\dots$. The order here is the order of observing them.
You then say that these variables are Bernoulli distributed. I would interpret it as follows. Let me shift to looking at a sequences or these variables.
$$
S^{(k)}=\{\,X^{(k)}_0,\,X^{(k)}_1,\,X^{(k)}_2,\dots\}
$$
You could then say something like:
$$
X^{(k)}_i\sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(\pi_i)
$$
i.e. different sequences have uncorrelated Bernoulli variables, but probability $\pi_i$ does depend on the position within the sequence (possibly). Next step, you could state that positional dependence is solely due to preceding values values. Which allows you to specify something like:
$$
\pi_i=\pi\mid X_{i-1},X_{i-2}\dots
$$
i.e. probability for the position depends only on previous measurements. This sort of assumes that previous measurements directly cause the next observation, with some noise. What would be an example of this? Something like winning and bribing, you win money in the previous bet, you then try to bribe the game operator with this money, and you are more likely to win next time.
another option is dependence on previous latent state:
$$
\pi_i=\pi\mid\pi_{i-1},\pi_{i-2}\dots
$$
this is more like doing well in tests whilst learning. There is some latent ability for you to do well in tests, and it could be growing over time, this could be captured as a recursive trend $\pi\mid\pi_{i-1},\pi_{i-2}$.
This is a bit like Moving Average vs Auto-Regression in ARMA models. The two ways to specify dependence are not mutually exclusive. You can mix them. Once you have decided on this, you can move to specifying the functional form of this dependence. It can be linear, can be non-linear etc.
You could also try avoiding, or at least reducing, latent parameters. For example, let $Y_i,Z_i\sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(\pi)$ and:
$$
X_i=\begin{cases}
X_{i-1}, & Y_i=0 \\
Z_i,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Most of these models can be fitted with maximum likelihood
